# Fallo en la creación de una columna nueva, con datos de otras

Tags: python-3.7

En el Dataframe que se importa con el script que adjunto, necesito crear una columna denominada "ROC". Su contenido debe ser: ROC = [(Cierre actual – Cierre 9 períodos atrás) / (Cierre 9 períodos atrás)] X 100.

```
# Importar cotizaciones de un único ISIN
import os
import pandas as pd
url = "https://funds.ddns.net/f.php?isin=" + "ES0114638036"
df = pd.read_html(url, header=0, thousands="", parse_dates=True,  decimal="," )[0]
df.columns = (["Date", "Close"])
df = df.set_index("Date")

# Doble de cruces de medias móviles de 50 y 200 días
df['MA50'] = df["Close"].rolling(50).mean().dropna()

df = df[["MA50"] ].copy(deep=True)
df1 = df.sort_index(ascending=False) 
df1= df1.dropna()

for i in range (0, df1.shape[0]-9):
    df1["ROC"] = ((df1.iloc[i, 0] - df1.iloc[i+9, 0]) / df1.iloc[i+9, 0])*100
    
df1[:10]
```

El script crea la columna, pero en cada registro introduce un mismo valor, lo cual es incorrecto. ¿Cual puede ser el fallo?. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar el método [values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) que devuelve la representación del dataframe y vas reasignando por cada iteración.

```
# Inicializa vacía la columna del dataframe
df1["ROC"] = ''

for i in range (0, df1.shape[0]-9):
    df1["ROC"].values[i] = ((df1.iloc[i, 0] - df1.iloc[i+9, 0]) / df1.iloc[i+9, 0])*100
```

**Si imprimes las dos primeras filas del dataframe**:

```
print(df1.head(2))
```

**El resultado es el siguiente**:

```
               MA50      ROC
Date                        
2019-10-17  45.3248  2.29992
2019-10-16  45.2248  2.35004
```

Y si haces un print dentro del bucle `for` de cada valor de lo que te devuelve tu operación, verás que los dos primeros resultados son:

```
2.29992461483596
2.3500443575398657
```

Por lo cual está asignando correctamente el valor a cada fila en cada iteración.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Tengo otro problema. Añade el resultado pero con el dtype "object". Añado ".astype("float64")", pero no me convierte los números a decimales.

Comment: pd.to_numeric(df1["ROC"]), tampoco me los convierte.

Comment: Intenta añadiendo justo debajo de donde inicializas la columna vacía (`df1["ROC"] = ''`) lo siguiente: `df1["ROC"] = pd.to_numeric(df1["ROC"])`

Comment: Gracias. así, si modifica el dtype.

Answer (score 0):

La opción con el método "values", soluciona el problema. ¿Por qué no funciona con el método "at"?

```
# Inicializa vacía la columna del dataframe
df1["ROC"] = ''

for i in range (0, df1.shape[0]-9):
    df1.at(i, "ROC") = ((df1.iloc[i, 0] - df1.iloc[i+9, 0]) / df1.iloc[i+9, 0])*100
    
df1[:3]
```

Comment: df1.at(i, "ROC") debe ser df1.at[, "ROC")df1.at(i, "ROC"]